# OSX Malicious Terminal Command (colon, brackets, curly brackets, apersand, etc)

Tags: bash, macos

Ok, so someone "challenged" me to enter this into my OSX Terminal, but I have no idea what it would do:

**WARNING** to the reader: the following line can be harmful; do **NOT** enter it unless you know what you are doing:

```
:(){ :|:& };:
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a [fork bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb). Don't do it. (Actually, as GB pointed out quickly, the copy here started out as a broken fork bomb. It was missing its final colon.) Still, if someone says, "Try this command" while snickering, and you don't know what it does, common sense says...

Edit: [The one you have here](http://www.digitalcraft.org/?artikel_id=292) is pretty famous as a [work of art](http://www.p0es1s.net/en/projects/jaromil.html) by Jaromil, a digital artist.

Comment: You'll want to note that OS X has something akin to max-procs-per-user on by default.  It won't take down your system like most distros will allow by default.

Answer (score 12):

Breaking down the command so it's actually understandable:

```
:() #Define new function
    #named ':'
{ #Begin function definition
  #block
  :|:& #Pipe the very ':' function through itself,
        #creating two processes, and make the
        #resulting copy run in the background
        #(the & part)
} #End function definition block
;: #Call ':' for the first time, initiating a chain
   #reaction: each instance of ':' will create two
   #more instances, ad infinitum
```

Then again, from my experience Mac OS X happens to have a per-user limit for the number of processes one can execute, so unless you actually have the guts to run the fork bomb under a `sudo -s` or `sudo -i` shell, you should be fine.

Comment: great explanation

Answer (score 3):

It does nothing harmful, since Mac OS X has a (per-user) upper bound for number of processes.

Comment: I know this thread is pretty old, but I just wanted to add that I've tried this in my Mac OSX Terminal, and the process got killed before anything bad happened. (Note: I did try it inside of a virtual machine first.) However, when I tried it in a Windows VM bash shell, its dirty work was never stopped. Interesting stuff!

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely nothing. It's an incomplete version of the "fork bomb", missing a colon at the end.

Comment: Copied and pasted it wrongly - the original did have a colon at the end, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Fork bomb!

I mean... fun bomb! Give it a try inside a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

On properly configured systems it doesn't do much harm, you should be able to try it.